# Building a RS232 switch

Tags: wiring, switching, rs232

I have an RS232 input and 2 audio lines that I want to switch to either computer A or computer B depending on the state of a physical toggle switch. Can anyone point me in the right direction of what parts I'd need and how to wire this exactly?

I attached an image for clarification.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Use a 3PDT switch ... ?

Comment: I want to use only one switch in total. RS232 has 9 pins and the 2 audio lines 3 each. I don't think that works with a 3PDT switch?

Comment: @MikeD Then draw all the connections you wish to switch - don't skimp on this - also include consideration for signal 0 volts to be separated from audio 0 volts and that you need to establish what the likely common mode voltage disturbances are between computer A and computer B - the devil is in the detail and this is one certain to screw your audio big time if not designed correctly.

Comment: You're asking about a "RS232 input", so I assumed a single incoming data RX line. Is this not the case? Are you transmitting too? And you're also using *all* of the various flow-control lines (RTS, CTS, DSR, DTR)? Even RI??

Comment: And your audio is stereo?

Comment: Simple chip switch is CD4066, also see CD4051 CD4052 CD4053

Comment: google `rs232 ab switch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need all the control lines on the serial port you could re-allocate some of the pins on a 1990s-style [switch-box](https://www.showmecables.com/media/specs/47-200-020%20spec%20sheet.pdf) switch to your audio.

[image]

Switching or not switching the grounds may have a significant effect on your audio.

These multi-pole rotary switches are not all that common and if you need that many pins, taking them out of a box may be cheaper than buying the switch as a component, for a one-off.

Comment: If you need even more pins you can also still get parallel printer versions of these boxes on ebay. I don't see how you can beat the price of this type of box, switch and connector - and all you need to do is rewire it.